# Rails: Create a drop down list (within a form) where it's possible to select more than one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(I've made up the example below as it's clearer than going through my specific case.)

Suppose I have a form for a User, and that the underlying User table has a personality_traits field; an array of the user's personality traits.  Is there a standard way in rails to create a **drop-down** list so that the user can pick any number of a selection of attributes (e.g., "easy-going", "fun-loving", "quick-tempered"), and have these ultimately feed into the personality_traits field as an array?  If not, does anyone know of a particularly good method?

Comment: A dropdown is usually reserved for situations where the user will be selecting only one option.  If you are allowing the user to select more than one option you should use a series of check boxes or radio buttons.

Comment: I would like to second @ruby_newbie's remark; it's important to follow convention with web controls, and the convention with a dropdown list is that it is for selecting a single item (which is also why it displays only one item when collapsed). For selecting multiple items I would encourage the use of something like Rails' in-built collection_check_boxes method: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: Thanks.
@ConnorCMcKee - why is it important to follow convention?  I'm using the word 'dropdown' from a visual perspective (perhaps I shouldn't?), I'm not meaning to describe the method of implementation.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't use the collection_check_boxes method and make it appear as a dropdown (Justin's answer is pretty much spot-on actually in terms of effect)?

Comment: It is important purely from a User Experience perspective. Taking advantage of convention is one of the best ways to ensure a positive user experience. One of the first principles of web design as "getting rid of question marks" (Steve Krug). A multiple-select drop down raises question marks. When collapsed and expecting something that allows multiple selection the user questions the mechanism. Once collapsed again, the user questions the options they selected. Additionally, see: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/most-intuitive-multi-select-component-for-the-web

Answer (score 0):

[bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) will do what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks - the effect is pretty much exactly what I'm after.  However, I'd rather not use a plug-in unless it's very light-weight, if possible (especially if it requires Bootstrap).  Apologies for not being clearer.